# POST Request creates multiple objects AJAX/Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, ajax, django-rest-framework

I am trying to enable a user to create a new list for a dashboard. The problem I have is that when the user creates a new list the following behaviour occurs:

- User creates first list: The new list appears once
- User creates a second list: the second list appears twice
- User creates a third list: the third list appears three times
- ETC.

I'm not sure why this behaviour is occurring.

Ajax Call:

```js
//create new list
const createNewList = function(){
  $("#newlistmodal").modal('show');
  $("#save-list").click(function() {
    var listName = $("#newListName").val();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/api/userlist/',
      data: {
      csrfmiddlewaretoken: document.querySelector('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').value,
      'list_name' : listName
      },
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data.instance_id)
        var listId = data.instance_id;
        $("#newlistmodal").modal('hide');
          $("#userLists").append(
            `<li class="userlist" id="${listName}" data-name="${listName}" data-pk="${listId}">
              ${listName}
                <i id="dropdown" class="ml-4 dropdown fas fa-ellipsis-h" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"></i>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" id="${listName}-edit" data-name="${listName}" data-pk="${listId}">Edit List</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" id="${listName}-share" data-name="${listName}" data-pk="${listId}">Share</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" id="${listName}-delete" data-name="${listName}" data-pk="${listId}">Delete</a>    
            </li>
            `)
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Views.py (Using DRF)

```py
class UserListViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserListSerializer
 
    def get_queryset(self):
        return UserList.objects.filter(user__username=self.request.user)
    
    def create(self, request):
        serializer_class = UserListSerializer

        if self.request.method == "POST":
            user = self.request.user.id
            list_name = request.data.get('list_name')
            data = {'user': user, 'list_name': list_name}
            serializer = serializer_class(data=data)
            
            if serializer.is_valid():
                instance = serializer.save()
            
                return Response({'status' : 'ok', 'user' : user, 'instance_id':instance.id}, status=200)
    
            else:
                return Response({'error' : serializer.errors}, status=400)
```

Serializer:

```
class UserListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): #this is what we worked on on October 1
    class Meta:
        model = UserList
        fields = ['id', 'user', 'list_name']
```

HTML:

```html
   <div class="modal" id="newlistmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title">Create a New List</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Create a New List</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="newListName" placeholder="New List Name...">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button id="save-list" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Just to clarify: They are created correctly and only once in the DB, but appear multiple times in the frontend?

Comment: Hi there, I just had a look and looks like it creates multiple items in the DB too.

Comment: Follow up question. Looking at the code you shared, nothing seems out of place. Could you tell me: looking at the console, clicking on **submit** only calls the API once? Could you also share your `UserListSerializer` code?

Comment: Updated OP with serializer - yes I believe it is hitting the API once. Could it have something to do with what the suggested answer below said?

Comment: Hey @JordanKowal, sorry to tag you, any ideas what I could try?

Comment: You said `yes I believe it is hitting the API once`. Do you believe, or are you SURE? It's important to check and make sure of it. Either print the log in Django or simply press F12 in your browser, go to the network tab, and se how many calls are performed when submiting your list name. To know why things are displayed and created several times, we must check each step of the workflow to see where it goes wrong

Comment: Checked, it is hitting it multiple times.

Comment: Alright so if it's hitting it multiple times, it means the frontend/js is at fault. The most likely scenario is duplicated ID in your html, which makes jquery trigger the action several times when clicking on your submit button.

Comment: @JordanKowal the relevant id ``save-list`` only appears once in the html. Thanks for your assistance so far. I added the html to OP.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `$("#userLists")` is unique? e.g. if for each successful call you append an additional `<li` with `id="userLists"`, then your next call is going to append to two elements rather than one and so on.

Comment: Hey there looks like it creates multiple lists in the db!